# Gentoo failed to emerge GParted 0.25.0

Tags: gentoo, gcc, gparted

- My system is Gentoo 64 bit
- GCC version is gcc (Gentoo 5.3.0 p1.0, pie-0.6.5) 5.3.0.

I got this error while emerging sys-block/gparted-0.25.0

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib64/libgtkmm-2.4.so: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(std::string const&)'

My system has gparted-0.24.0 emerged, but it got "segment faults" when I try to launch it.

I think it is because I upgraded my GCC recently. I have followed the [wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Upgrading_GCC) to upgrade my system. But I still got this problem. It seems it is the only package I got trouble with after I upgrade my GCC.

I also tried to re-emerge packages that provide libgtkmm, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently at least one problem with newer compilers has been fixed in the current git master for GParted.  You might wish to try compiling from that.

Comment: If it is fixed on master, I'd rather wait for the Gentoo team to update the repository.